# putExtra when sending variables across activities in Android allows the variable to be set to null

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

To send a variable from a Fragment to an Activity, I have used putExtra and extras.getString. However, I discovered I am getting a NullPointerException when using Log.e to check the value due to variable in which I am passing becoming =null. This happens after I have started the activity.

So how do i prevent this from occurring. Thus keeping the value of the variable.

**Code for Fragment:**

```
    Integer IDPasser;
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ArticleViewer.class);
    IDPasser =  (Integer) data.ArticleID.toArray()[position];
    intent.putExtra("ArticleID",IDPasser);
    Log.e("Passer", IDPasser.toString()); //Shows that value is not = null.
    startActivity(intent);
```

**Code for Activity:**

```
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
      if (extras != null) {

             Integer IDPasser = extras.getInt("ArticleID");
             Log.e("TESTER", IDPasser.toString()); //NullPointerException due to IDPasser becoming = null.
            }
```

Comment: What would the string name be?

Comment: Are you able to provide an example since i'm not sure of the referencing part which you said can be confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Fragment` code is fine. In the `Activity`:

```
 int idPasser = getIntent().getIntExtra("ArticleID", 0);
```

The second parameter in `getIntExtra()` is the default value to return if an `int` extra that corresponds to the key `"ArticleID"` is not found.

Comment: For this line: Integer IDPasser = getIntent().getInt("ArticleID"); I am getting the error: "The method getInt(String) is undefined for the type Intent" on ".getInt".

Comment: Look at my answer again: `getIntExtra()`, not `getInt()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend making IDPasser an int not an Integer to avoid any confusion about whether the extra data is being passed as on Object or an int. I think you might be having a problem where you are inserting the value technically as putExtra(... Serializable) and expecting to get it out with extras.getInt(...)

```
int IDPasser;
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ArticleViewer.class);
IDPasser =  data.ArticleID.toArray()[position];
intent.putExtra("ArticleID", IDPasser);
Log.e("Passer", String.valueOf(IDPasser)); //Shows that value is not = null.
startActivity(intent);
```

Then:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        int IDPasser = extras.getInt("ArticleID");
        Log.e("TESTER", String.valueOf(IDPasser)); //NullPointerException due to IDPasser becoming = null.
    }
```